# Action controller: Exception Caught while trying to acces recently generated controller on empty Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails, just trying to follow some tutorials.I just entered:

```
rails generate controller helloWorld index
```

then i started rails server and tried to access http://localhost:3000/hello_world/index
and got

```
Action controller: Exception Caught 

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `rake db:create db:migrate` before starting the server.

If you did, pls check your database configuration in `config/database.yml`. If you can't figure it out, please let us know the contents of that file.